# Grouping Appenders At Logback?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback, appender

I have two appenders. One of them is DB appender and the other one is SMTPAppender. When I log a string with a special marker I want to use both my custom db appender and SMTPAppender. However I don't want to define two appenders everythime as like that:

```
<logger name="com.MyClass" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_DB"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_EMAIL"/>
</logger>
```

I want a special reference that as like that:

```
<appender-group ref="CUSTOM_COMBO">
    <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_DB"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_EMAIL"/>
</appender-group>

<logger name="com.MyClass" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="CUSTOM_COMBO"/>
</logger>
```

It should both call CUSTOM_DB and CUSTOM_EMAIL. How can I do that at Logback with slf4j?

Comment: Cool feature request. I don't think this exists in logback. You could put a bunch of appenders in the root logger and set your additivity flag to `true`.

Comment: What's the relation between loggers and markers in your use case?

Comment: @Ceki I want to have a marker that starts with CUSTOM. I will log with a marker as like CUSTOM.DB, CUSTOM.EMAIL etc. I want to make a pattern match at my appender that will check either given marker starts with "CUSTOM." or not. If it starts with "CUSTOM." and appender is CUSTOM_DB it will write into DB, if it starts with "CUSTOM." and appender is CUSTOM_EMAIL it will send an email. Thats why I want a appender group. On the other hand if I can write a custom appender-group and inside it if I can make a pattern match as like MARKER starts with "CUSTOM." or not it will be another cool thing.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want. Can you clarify the question some more?

Comment: I want to make a ref into a logical group of appenders instead of just one appender.

Comment: Why do you set additivity to false, don't you want some root with both appenders?

Answer (score 1):

So from https://tersesystems.com/blog/2019/05/27/application-logging-in-java-part-5/

```
public class CompositeAppender<E> extends UnsynchronizedAppenderBase<E> implements AppenderAttachable<E> {

    protected AppenderAttachableImpl<E> aai = new AppenderAttachableImpl<E>();

    @Override
    protected void append(E eventObject) {
        aai.appendLoopOnAppenders(eventObject);
    }

    // AppenderAttachable API delegates to aai in all cases
}
```

and

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%-5level] %logger{15} -  message%n%xException{10}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>file.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - %message</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE_AND_FILE" class="com.tersesystems.logback.CompositeAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_AND_FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd need to write your own CompoundAppender, Details on how to write a custom appender are at http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html.